# "Flatten" pandas column that is JSON to create new row but keep ID

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am looking to "flatten" the JSON in this table. I am trying to use pandas but it doesn't need to use pandas. I have tried both the explode method and json_normalize() but neither worked. Maybe I used them wrong?

I'm trying to go from this:

| order_id | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'key': '100', 'product': 'soap'},{key': '104', 'product': 'butter'}] |
| 2 | [{'key': '97', 'product': 'baby wipes'},{key': '104', 'product': 'butter'},{key': '107', 'product': 'milk'}] |
| 3 | [{'key': '95', 'product': 'diapers'},{key': '104', 'product': 'butter'},{key': '110', 'product': 'toothpaste'}] |
| 4 | [{'key': '100', 'product': 'soap'},{key': '101', 'product': 'yogurt'},{key': '111', 'product': 'hair brush'},{key': '112', 'product': 'hair dye'}] |

to this:

| order_id | key | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | soap |
| 1 | 104 | butter |
| 2 | 97 | baby wipes |
| 2 | 104 | butter |
| 2 | 107 | milk |
| 3 | 95 | diapers |
| 3 | 104 | butter |
| 3 | 110 | toothpaste |
| 4 | 100 | soap |
| 4 | 101 | yogurt |
| 4 | 111 | hair brush |
| 4 | 112 | hair dye |

Any help or point in the right direction is extremely appreciated!

Comment: There are many ways to do that. But you probably should act BEFORE creating this dataframe with JSON in its cell. How do you get to this df?

Comment: its CSV I downloaded from a SQL table. The JSON is saved like that in the SQL table field.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` to get the objects out of the lists, and then convert the list of objects to a dataframe and concatenate it:

```
new_df = df.explode('JSON')
new_df = pd.concat([new_df.drop('JSON', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(new_df['JSON'].tolist(), index=new_df.index)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   order_id  key     product
0         1  100        soap
0         1  104      butter
1         2   97  baby wipes
1         2  104      butter
1         2  107        milk
2         3   95     diapers
2         3  104      butter
2         3  110  toothpaste
3         4  100        soap
3         4  101      yogurt
3         4  111  hair brush
3         4  112    hair dye
```

Note that *before* you run that code, you may need to run one of the following two lines to convert the JSON strings to actual Python dicts:

```
import json
new_df['JSON'] = new_df['JSON'].apply(json.loads)
```

or

```
import ast
new_df['JSON'] = new_df['JSON'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: Since this came from an SQL, there's a chance the JSON part is actually a string

Comment: Hmm...I guess you're right. But in the OP's table, it uses single quotes (`'`), which made me think that they're Python dicts.

Comment: idk why but the .explode does nothing for me?

Comment: @learningtocode0728 Check the bottom of the answer. I added some more info that may help.

Comment: THANK YOU! Converting the string to JSON helped!